# Split a string by forward slash but ignore the <\ in the string

Tags: php, preg-split

I have string similar to this

```
word1/word2/word3/<b>word3</b>
```

I want to explode this string by forward slash. So that I can get the following result.

```
Array = (
[0] => 'word1',
[1] => 'word2',
[2] => 'word3',
[3] => '<b>word3</b>'
);
```

But I'm unable to get the above result. Instead I'm getting the following result

```
Array = (
    [0] => 'word1',
    [1] => 'word2',
    [2] => 'word3',
    [3] => '<b>word3<',
    [4] => 'b>'
    );
```

What regular expression should I use for this to use the `preg_split` function to achieve the expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `preg_split` function and specific regex pattern:

```
$s = 'word1/word2/word3/<b>word3</b>';
$result = preg_split('~(?<!<)/~', $s);
print_r($result);
```

- `~` - treated as regex expression separator
- `(?<!<)/` - negative lookbehind assertion, assures that forward slash `/` is not preceded by `<`

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => word1
    [1] => word2
    [2] => word3
    [3] => <b>word3</b>
)
```